# How to extract string that occurs between on the first single quote and then extract the string that occurs between the second single quote separately

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex

How to extract the string that occurs between the first single quote and then extract the string that occurs between the second single quote separately in a pandas dataframe. I have tried `(\'(.*)\')`, but it extracts all strings between quotes regardless of the appearance.
Example:

`This is 'Test1' and this is 'Test2'`

I want first to extract `Test1` and then extract `Test2` separately.

Comment: `re.findall(r".*?'(.*?)'.*?'(.*?)'","This is 'Test1' and this is 'Test2'")` if you want them in pairs